# How to use both python 2.7 and 3 in gem5?

Tags: python, gem5

I have a machine with two gem5-repository instances: one that I keep up-to-date, and the other using an aged version that I cannot update yet.

I was using Ubuntu 16.04, and the current gem5 version has deprecated the use of python 2.7. I was postponing upgrading my OS, and using a few workarounds (Reverting the commit `scons: Set the minimum scons version to 3.0`, and manually adding `EM_RISCV` to `src/base/loader/elf_object.cc`); however, recently things got messy, so I was forced to do it in order to use SCons 3 and python3.

After trying on both Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, I still could not compile due to the use of metaclasses in some python class.

The real issue is clear, though; even though I have python3 installed (in `/usr/bin/`), python3-config could not be found:

```
Info: Using Python config: python2.7-config
```

How can I use both python 2.7 and 3 in the same machine to compile different versions of gem5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SCons can't find python3-config, manually override PYTHON_CONFIG with its location, and set the proper environment.

```
alias scons2="/usr/bin/env python2.7 $(which scons) PYTHON_CONFIG=$(which python2.7-config)"
alias scons3="/usr/bin/env python3 $(which scons) PYTHON_CONFIG=$(which python3-config)"
```

Then, to compile the updated repository:

```
scons3 -j5 ./build/ARM/gem5.opt
```

To compile the one that needs python 2.7:

```
scons2 -j5 ./build/ARM/gem5.opt
```